# Immutables class containing list does not throw exception when built without list

Tags: java, immutables-library

I have a class that I expect to throw an exception if it is attempted to be built without either name or stuff being specified in the builder. This happens if I don't set "name", but not if I don't set "stuff".

```
@Value.Immutable
public abstract class Data {
  public abstract String name();
  public abstract List<String> stuff();
}
```

Can somebody point out how I can enforce requiring the list to be specified or objects to be added to the list using the Immutables library?

Answer (score 1):

You should implement a precondition check as [described in the documentation](http://immutables.github.io/immutable.html#precondition-check-method).

For your class, it could look something like the following:

```
@Value.Check
protected void check() {
    Preconditions.checkState(!stuff().isEmpty(), "At least one stuff must be specified.");
}
```